# ConsoleReporter () is not satisfied in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

To test the javascript-code uses Jasmine v.2.0 + Karma v.0.12

There jasmine-test:

```
define(function() {

    describe("someTest", function () {

        it('someTest_Test', function () {

            var ConsoleReporter = jasmine.ConsoleReporter();
            var options = {
                timer: new jasmine.Timer,
                print: function () {
                    console.log.apply(console, arguments)
                }
            };
            var consoleReporter = new ConsoleReporter(options);
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(consoleReporter); 

            expect( "someText" ).toEqual( "someText" );

        });

    });

});
```

For console output test results you plan to use the console.

Nevertheless, as a result of the code above will get an error:
"TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Comment: For what you need console reporter? You can install PhantomJS and add phantomjs-runner and you will see output on console.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I have realized that you are not using Jasmine 2.0 but **Karma-Jasmine 2.0**

There are some differences like missing files:

- https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js
- https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/lib/console/console.js